# Call Microsoft Graph API Using Azure AD 1.0 Endpoint Client Credentials Flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to access the Microsoft Graph API using an access token obtained through the Azure Active Directory 1.0 Endpoint with the Client Credentials OAuth 2 flow?

For example:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
grant_type=client_credentials,
client_id={app id registered in azure portal},
client_secret={registered app key},
resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

When I use the token returned from this request, I get the following error trying to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups.

Decoded JWT

Header

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "HHByKU-0DqAqMZh6ZFPd2VWaOtg",
  "kid": "HHByKU-0DqAqMZh6ZFPd2VWaOtg"
}
```

Payload

```
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenant id}/",
  "iat": 1504804880,
  "nbf": 1504804880,
  "exp": 1504808780,
  "aio": "Y2FgYDiiO8/s3smXRdxLg87zBPRNAwA=",
  "appid": "{client id}",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenant id}/",
  "oid": "{enterprise app object id}",
  "sub": "{enterprise app object id}",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "{tenant id}",
  "uti": "uIzrJNpHcEGXoQ4ZKZgqAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3537d28e-a061-4430-aef5-4a75bf791d90",
      "date": "2017-09-07T16:38:26"
    }
  }
}
```

I've ensured the application has the correct permissions assigned through the portal.  Under Required Permissions > Application Permissions, "Read and write all groups" is selected.

[Azure Portal Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tzyo.png)

Is there anything I'm missing or is this not possible?

Comment: Can you check the JWT in a service like https://jwt.io and make sure it contains the *roles* claim with the necessary permission?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any roles listed in the JWT.  In that case is there something I need to add to my request?

Comment: Have you pressed the *Grant permissions* button in the place where you set up the permission requirements for the app? And also, make sure it was Microsoft Graph API that you requested the permissions for.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before and after clicking _Grant permissions_.  I also verified the API was _Microsoft Graph_.I added a link to a screenshot of my permissions settings.

Comment: Could you share the JWT token? (removing any sensitive properties) If it was a problem with missing Role Claims, I would expect the error to be "Insufficient Privileges". This error implies something is wrong with the token itself.

Comment: If you have granted the permission. (You can check by going to Enterprise Applications and finding your app, there should be a link for granted permissions). Also sometimes it can take a while for new permissions to show up in tokens.

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi I'd be happy to share the JWT, but I'm not sure which fields need to be removed.

Comment: @juunas I looked under Enterprise Applications and found my app.  It says the "Read and write all groups" Application permission on Microsoft Graph was granted through Admin Consent.

Comment: You need to only remove what you feel uncomfortable with. Like First Name, Tenant ID, UPN/Email, etc...

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi I added the JWT content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your JWT token, the Audience Value (`aud`) is wrong.

If you are trying to call `https://graph.microsoft.com` or any of it's APIs, you need a token with the `aud` claim of `https://graph.microsoft.com` or `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`.

The token you have is for the AAD Graph API, `https://graph.windows.net` a.k.a. `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`

While these two resources look similar in both URL and GUID form, they are completely separate identities. You should confirm throughout your code that you are specifying the correct resource value when retrieving your access token. Your small sample above implies that you are doing it correct, but the token shows that you are not.

Comment: You're right.  I was sending _scope=https://graph.microsoft.com_, not _resource=https://graph.microsoft.com_ like I said I was.  I swear I had already tried it both ways, but it's working now.  It could have been that I hadn't tried it this way after clicking _Grant permissions_ until now.  Thank you.

Comment: I am glad this solved your issue. Feel free to accept my response as the correct answer so that others may know that this problem is resolved.